# How to rewrite with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I'm pretty new to **.htaccess** and have a question..

How would I rewrite

`http://example.com/forums/view.php?v=Topic%20Name&a=64`                                                                            to `http://example.com/forums/view/Topic-Name/64`?

as stated above, I'm new to this..

Also, how would I replace `-` with   while keeping normal dashes?

**Example:** `Hi There-Bye!` would then convert into `Hi-There-Bye!`

Which would then convert back to `Hi There-Bye!` with `php and .htaccess`?

Comment: There's quite a lot of material on the web about this already. Can you outline what you've found and tried?

Comment: 1. Look at the hundreds of already answered questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=htaccess+url+rewrite).
2. You keep multiple entries, for the same ID, so you know which one is the url path and which is the title. You don't change them back.

Comment: You couldn't convert it back to that, as you don't know if a `-` was a `-` originally or a ` `. What you can do is store that url-friendly topic name with your topic data, and search on that.

Comment: In terms of your slugified URL, the reverse conversion isn't possible, since if `-` is to be converted to a space, then they would both be converted. However, in general you don't need to do the reverse conversion, since usually the primary key is also added to the URL, and the slug is just for SEO purposes.

Comment: @Wrikken Thought so.. This is what I have so far, which doesn't work @halfer `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /view/(.*)/(.*)$ /view.php?v=$1&a=$2`

Comment: ^ Great, edit it into your question please, to stop it being put on hold.

Comment: ^ Google for halfer's mention of 'slugs', it'll probably show you a lot of examples how to use them, but it would likely require a table change to store it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question is pretty basic. You need an external redirect from the 'ugly' (but working) url to the seo url and an internal rewrite from the seo url to the 'ugly' url. They can all be written in the following format:

```
#External redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /forums/view\.php\?v=([^&]+)&a=(.+)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /forums/view/%1/%2 [R,L]
#Change above [R,L] to [R=301,L] after testing all rules work as expected

#Internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^forums/view/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /forums/view.php?v=$1&a=$2 [L]
```

The second thing is not possible. There is no way to distinguish between the dash between `Hi` and `There` and the dash between `There` and `Bye`. I would say: Don't bother. It's a seo-url. If you want to have fancy seo-url's, you'll have to alter your database to contain those fancy seo-urls.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great..
One thing, What if a user entered a slash on the end of the url? How would I got about working around that?

Comment: That's what the `/?$` is doing ;-) `/?` matches if `/` appears exactly 0 or 1 times. `$` is the end of the string.

Comment: @Sumurari8 http://example.com/forums/view/Test%20Topic/5 works, but http://example.com/forums/view/Test%20Topic/5/ does not.

Comment: It *should* (I haven't tested it, but it is pretty much routine writing for me at this point) work with the rules I have here (but that doesn't help you much, does it?). It could be that other rewriterules are working on the url with the /, or that an other Apache directive decides that something else needs to be done with the url. You can try to add `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R,L]` above your rules (change `R` to `R=301` once everything works) to remove said /, but this might not work if something else is playing with the url before mod_rewrite does that.

Comment: Even though it is horrible to read in the comments, there doesn't seem to be anything strange happening with urls ending on `/` there.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite using below method.

```
RewriteRule ^example/(.*)\.html$ example/test.php?param=$1
```

Comment: I do not want file extensions, and I have multiple query items.

Comment: then remove the .html part and you can query multiple items too:)

Comment: for multiple query item use this RewriteRule /example/(.*)/(.*)$ /example.php?parameter1=$1&parameter2=$2

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^forums/view/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /forums/view.php?v=$1&a=$2 [L]
```