# Reverse mod_rewrite in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Is there a way to change the url with .htaccess but don't make a redirect?

I have links like

```
<a href="?p=hello_world">Hello World</a>
```

in my script (dir/index.php) and want to change the url to `url.de/dir/hello_world`.

My current .htaccess file:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(.*)$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1? [R,L]  
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

but now from `localhost/dir/?p=hello_world` the url changed to `localhost/hello_world` without `/dir`. And I don't know the name of the directory because everyone should be able to use my project without changing this .htaccess on his server.

Comment: I find it hard to understand what url should be displayed, and what url should be loaded on the server. What you have to do though, is having an external redirect (`[R,L]` flag) to the nice url and an internal rewrite (only `[L]` flag) to the old url. For the external redirect you match `%{THE_REQUEST}`. [This answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20882418/2209007) might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Determine the RewriteBase dynamically (\2 is backreference for string after 1st slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]

# External redirect from /dir?p=hello_world to /dir/hello_world
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?p=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}%1? [R=302,L]

# Internal rewrite from /dir/hello_world to /dir/index.php?p=hello_world
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the name of directory it should work for every url.

Comment: I copied it and it changes ?p=hello_world to a singe / and unfortunately I don't understand your code :/

Comment: I changed RewriteRule `^ %{ENV:BASE}/%2? [R=302,L]` to `RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}%1? [R=302,L]` that works fine

Comment: Thanks, I edited it as per your comment. If it worked out please consider marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: I deleted the `/`as well with your version it will `..//hello_world`

Comment: Thanks, Yes I realized that since `%{ENV:BASE}` has `/` both at starting and end positions. It is edited now.

Comment: Would be awesome if you could explain it a bit with comments inside the code :)

Comment: Sure I will add the comments n my answer.